# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object GetValue(...)'

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

My issue is I need to query on the value of a property in a generic class. The property is tagged with an attribute.

See the following code:

```
 var rowKeyProperty = EFUtil.GetClassPropertyForRowKey<T>();
 var tenantKeyProperty = EFUtil.GetClassPropertyForTenantKey<T>();

 var queryResult =
                objContext.CreateObjectSet<T>().Single(l => (((int) tenantKeyProperty.GetValue(l, null)) == tenantKey) &&
                                                            (((int)rowKeyProperty.GetValue(l, null)) == KeyValue));
```

The rowKeyProperty and tenantKeyProperty are of type System.Reflection.PropertyInfo.

I understand why I am getting the error. When the linq query is translated to SQL, it can't understand the property.GetValue.

However, I'm completely stumped as to a work around here. Does anyone have any ideas how to achieve this? Thx.

Comment: The only way you'll be able to build EF-compatible queries using reflected properties is to build the expression trees yourself.

Comment: How are you determining which properties you need to get?

Comment: There is an attribute associated with the property. I call an attribute.isdefined return the property with that being true.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to actually build up the `Expression` objects to represent the expression that you want this to mimic, in this case the expression you want to represent is:

```
l => l.SomeProperty == SomeValue
```

So you need to build up each component of that bit by bit, from creating the parameter, defining the equality operator, the property access, the constant value, etc.

```
public static Expression<Func<TItem, bool>> PropertyEquals<TItem, TValue>(
    PropertyInfo property, TValue value)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TItem));
    var body = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(param, property),
        Expression.Constant(value));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TItem, bool>>(body, param);
}
```

Once you have all of that you can call it using the data that you have:

```
var queryResult = objContext.CreateObjectSet<T>()
    .Where(PropertyEquals<T, int>(tenantKeyProperty, tenantKey))
    .Where(PropertyEquals<T, int>(rowKeyProperty, KeyValue))
    .Single();
```

Comment: Confirmed this generates the correct query in SQL profiler. Thx Servy.

Comment: This has a problem when param is a DateTime.

Comment: @muttley91 And what's the problem you're having?

Comment: Error in `Expression.Property(param, property)` when it's DateTime. `Property 'System.DateTime LastUpdate' is not defined for type 'DataAccess.WorkOrder'`

Comment: @YusrilMaulidanRaji You're error is telling you what's wrong.  There is no property of that name and type for the object you're trying to get it from.

Comment: Ugh, my bad. The type of the object is referencing to the wrong object. Thanks anyway!

Comment: That's super sick. Thank you so very much. Now I have a working CRUD extension I can just inherit from any WCF service, and it's only because your really slick contribution, Thank you a lot!

Comment: A really elegant solution, works perfectly. THANK YOU! :)

Answer (score 2):

Appendix here... Following @Servy answer and based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553836/how-to-create-an-expression-tree-to-do-the-same-as-startswith) topic with a nice answer by @TomBrothers, you can use the same logic to make a `StartsWith` (or similar) function:

```
public static Expression<Func<TItem, bool>> PropertyStartsWith<TItem>(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, string value)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TItem));

    var m = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(param, propertyInfo);
    var c = Expression.Constant(value, typeof(string));
    var mi = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
    var body = Expression.Call(m, mi, c);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TItem, bool>>(body, param);
}
```

In this case, it forces `value` to be a string.

Answer (score 1):

It is more correct to specify the type in *Expression.Constant(value, typeof(TValue)))*

```
public static Expression<Func<TItem, bool>> PropertyEquals<TItem, TValue>(
        string property, TValue value)
    {
        var xParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TItem));
        var body = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(xParameter, property), Expression.Constant(value, typeof(TValue)));
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TItem, bool>>(body, xParameter);
    }
```

Or, like this, to check the property. [ChangeType](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18015612/6393097)

```
public static Expression<Func<TItem, bool>> PropertyEquals<TItem, TValue>(
        string property, TValue value)
    {
        var xParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TItem));
        var type = typeof(TItem).GetProperty(property).PropertyType;
        value = ChangeType<TValue>(value);
        BinaryExpression body = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(xParameter, property), Expression.Constant(value, type));

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TItem, bool>>(body, xParameter);
    }
```

What is it for. I check all class references to classes, I look for "..ID" entries. Somewhere I have a type "int" and "int?".

```
public class BudgetLimit : BaseRecord
{
    [Required]
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; } 
    public virtual Department Department { get; set;}

    public int? ProjectID { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You add .AsEnableable after the LINQ statement. 
e.g objectdata.AsEnumerable()
[enter link description here](http://www.jomendez.com/2015/09/28/orderby-argument-as-string-using-linq-c/)