# Inverting the logic of a MemberExpression

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

Taking the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553836/how-to-create-an-expression-tree-to-do-the-same-as-startswith) question; how would we modify the logic to perform a "! StartsWith" ? i.e. simply negating the logical result of the expression call.

Comment: How about `Expression.Not`?

Comment: @thehennyy awesome. I was looking in all the wrong places to find a way of doing this. Never thought to search what was available in "Expression". Thanks ! Can you not add your comment as an answer ? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build a logial not you can use the `Expression.Not` method.

Have a look at the msdn for an example:

> Creates a UnaryExpression that represents a bitwise complement operation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.not?view=netframework-4.7.2